# webapi: Multiple actions were found that match the request

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I can't seem to get the ActionName attribute to have any effect. the webapi is still matching both of the get methods:

The routes are set up as follows:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static string ControllerOnly = "ApiControllerOnly";
    public static string ControllerAndId = "ApiControllerAndId";
    public static string ControllerAction = "ApiControllerAction";

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerOnly,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}"
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerAndId,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: null, //defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional } //,
            constraints: new { id = @"^\d+$" } // id must be all digits
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: ControllerAction,
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
        );

    }
}
```

and the controller is:

```
public class MultipleActionsproblemController : ApiController
{

    // GET: api/multipleactionsproblem/method1
    [ActionName("method1")]
    public string Getmethod1()
    {
        return "method one";
    }

    // GET: api/multipleactionsproblem/method2
    [ActionName("method2")]
    public string Getmethod2()
    {
        return "method two";
    }

}
```

When I try visit /api/multipleactionproblem/method1 or /api/multipleactionproblem/method1 both of the get methods match. it does not use the action name.

Please could you advise me at to where I am going wrong.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I have managed to sort it out, the code above that I posted is infact ok, I had actually doubled up on my route configuration in the routeconfig and the WebapiConfig.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to remove the first of the three routes, you don't seem to need it since `{id}` in second route is optional. Would that solve your problem?

Comment: it isn't very clear in the code snippet but the parameter being optional is actually commented out in the second route.

Comment: Oh, I see. But still, having both the first route, and the second with `id` required, seems to me like the same as having only the second route with `id` optional. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes that would be the same but the second one is no longer optional as I commented the optional line out. The second one requires the I'd to be numeric